# Edit Firefox Devtools key bindings

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, codemirror, firefox-developer-tools

Since Firefox 33, there has been a GUI option in the dev tools to use different style key bindings in the editor. This is great, but this is where the functionality ends. **How can I edit specific key bindings for the editor?**

I use Sublime key bindings, but one annoyance is that it captures <kbd>cmd/ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and transposes characters instead of opening a new tab. This is incredibly annoying, and I've been looking for a way to edit [this file](http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/devtools/sourceeditor/codemirror/keymap/sublime.js) from the FF source code, but can't find it anywhere. Downloading the FF source code, editing it, and creating my own build is not an option.

Comment: Can you [log a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools) for this? The ST2 keybindings aren't well tested, this would help us out.

Comment: Bug created [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1094591).

Comment: @canuckistani There's been no feedback on the bug. Any chance you could confirm it?